# Double error after start working with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After start using constraint layout my app does not build. It shows an error 
[image]
This thing maybe fixed when I implement each library separately.
This error FOR now doesn't show but and not compile
Now dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

I have done already Clean -> Rebuild also i tried to change libraries from that error manually but no results. Also after all that work with manual working i received new error 
[image]

My OLD VERSION gradle file code below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.borisruzanov.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "auto"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    //General
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'

    //Images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

    //Network
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Figured out that Firebase using support library different version. How I can change it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this from two days and now I solved it today these are the steps

First Try this in your app level gradle file

```
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}`
```

if it does not solve try logging dependencies run this command

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

in your android studio's Terminal Tab it will log all the dependency tree of your project

then find which libraries are using duplicating dependencies

for example

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1' is using duplicate dependencies
```

so change

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

to

```
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support'
 }
```

Thats It..

Comment: hmmm anyway it shows error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex